# How to make scenarios independent

Tags: android, cucumber, appium, gherkin

I have a framework with cucumber.

My feature file looks like:

```
Feature: Test
  Background: Launch app
     Given Click on app
     And app is opened

  Scenario: scenario 1
     When click on blabla
     Then see blabla

  Scenario: scenario 2
     When click on qwert
     Then see qwert
```

If scenario 1 is failed on Then step, then it goes to scenario 2, but failed on step from Background 'And app is opened'.
Why it not restart app, when go to scenario 2.enter code here

Comment: We need to see more code. Can you post the code for the step definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Information that you provided is not enough but i can make a guess.
`Background` case runs before every scenario, that means, that if `scenario 1` failed in, for example, some screen in the application, cucumber will try to `Click on app` before `scenario 2`. But, as you can see, there is no `app` that is available to be clicked. You need to change your step definition of the `Click on app`, for example add some condition:

```
if (app.isVisible) {
   click();
 } else {
   //app already launed
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're struggling to reset the application to its initial state so that other tests would run seamlessly irrespective of previous tests' result. In your example, make sure you close/kill your app by using @After hook. Something like this.

```
public class Hooks{
static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void beforeHook(Scenario scenario){
 driver = new ChromeDriver(); //initialize with capabilities for your webapp/mobile app respectively.
}

@After
public void afterHook(Scenario scenario){
   driver.quit();
}

public static void getDriver(){
return driver;
}
}

public class StepDefinitions{

@Given("click on app")
public void launchApp(){
 driver = Hooks.getDriver(); // initialize your app here
}
}
```

For further [references](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#scenario-hooks)